# Does EPOLLEXCLUSIVE option work with multiple processes?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll

I'm now working with a server using fork to generate multiple processes to handle network connections. And I saw [EPOLLEXCLUSIVE](https://lwn.net/Articles/633422/#excl) option in epoll_ctl(). In the page, the option is said show that it works with multiple threads program, but later it is said work with multiple processed program.

So I wonder whether the option can work with multiple processes? (It means only wake up one process for the same epollfd that forked from parent process)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since Nginx turns `accept_mutex` default to `off`, it seems that it should work with multiple process program. So I came here for asure, can anyone give me a clear result please? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I find an article about this question here finally, and the answer is yes, it can work with multiple process.

The link is https://mvitolin.wordpress.com/2015/12/05/endurox-testing-epollexclusive-flag/